# $feedburner_id declared in newsletter.php is not available in n-feedburner.php

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, global-variables, feedburner

I have two php files namely:

1. newsletter.php, and
2. n-feedburner.php

> Let me first tell you what is the code written in `n-feedburner.php`→

The relevant code in the newsletter.php looks like this →

```
if($newsletter_provider == 'feedburner')
                    {
                        locate_template('inc/widgets/newsletter/n-feedburner.php',true,false);
                    }
```

But when we have this arrangement the Feedburner subscription system doesn't work.

However,

when we use this arrangement →

then things start to work.
Reason I find is:

`<?php echo $feedburner_id; ?>` doesnt work alone in `n-feedburner.php`
$feedburner_id: this is declared in newsletter.php so it is not available in `n-feedburner.php`

what is the solution? I want to keep the files separate because as API's will increases such as MailChimp, constant contact it will be important to keep the code clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following, which will retrieve the file and include it.

require( locate_template('inc/widgets/newsletter/n-feedburner.php', false) ) ;

also you can pass variable to n-feedburner.php using Global variable or any similar methods.

Comment: Please elaborate this → `also you can pass variable to n-feedburner.php using Global variable or any similar methods.

`

Comment: i mean using set_query_var or using php global $global_variable

Comment: this is generating bug → `require( locate_template('inc/widgets/newsletter/n-feedburner.php', false) ) ;`